# Excel VBA - Sum function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to calculate the sum of my columns (column I). From 1 to the last record in I it has. When I record a macro I get this as output, but this is gibberish to me.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-4]C)"
```

I found another topic and there they said

```
LastRow = .Range("I" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row  
Range("I"&LastRow) = "SUM(I1:I...)"
```

Except in my case, I can't figure how to enter the lastrow of I in it.
All help is welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of referencing a cell - 'R1C1' and 'A1'. The former works like co-ordinates, with a relative number of rows (R) and cells (C).

The other reference style refers to the cell name on the sheet - B6, F67 etc.

Let's say you want to put your `Sum()` in cell `B1` and `LastRow` has a value of 6:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "=Sum(I1:I" & LastRow & ")"
```

Would insert the following function in cell `B1`:

```
=SUM(I1:I6)
```

Comment: Wow ... It seems it makes a big difference when you use spaces. FML

Comment: I tried it like this `Range("I" & LastRow) = "=SUM(I1:I"&LastRow&")"`